# how can I get back my paypal classic api information?

Tags: java, paypal

I'm going to use paypal on my website. As you know paypal has upgraded their developers' website. But after I switched to the new site (developer.paypal.com) and migrated my test accounts from the old site, all the API information and test accounts have gone and I can't find them any more.

From the documentation I know I have to go to "Profile"->"API credentials" to get it(https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/#credentials). but I even couldn't find "Profile".

I can open the dashboard. But on the dashboard there are only REST API Apps, credentials and test accounts.

I also surfed www.x.com and was not able to find anything useful.

Could you guys tell me where to find those information?

Also I want to know what paypal API I should use to implement below business logic:

The first step, user A will pay money to my site. 
The second step, User B will provide service to user A. 
The third step, user A will confirm he/she has received the service. 
The forth step, my site will release the money and transfer it to user B.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find classic API credentials in sandbox / test by going to www.sandbox.payal.com and logging in to the seller account. Next, go to 'Profile' in here followed by 'API Access'.
The same navigation can be used for www.paypal.com for retrieving live API credentials.

Comment: It works. One more thing to tell other friends: you must be a verified account. but the sandbox site of paypal can't send verification email, so you have to contact paypal's customer service so that they can set your account as verified manually. then you can continue your test

Comment: PayPal customer service cannot set this; PayPal MTS (Merchant Technical Service) *can*, but you also *can* receive email in sandbox. Any emails triggered in sandbox are available as "notifications" under https://developer.paypal.com/ > Notification > Sandbox notifications. Hope this clears it up! Alternatively, you can simply create a buyer or seller account via https://developer.paypal.com/ which is verified by default.